# Nginx changes url to backend url

Tags: nginx

i have 2 backend servers listening on `80` and `443` ports:

- a.example.com
- b.example.com

when i get `http://a.example.com` at `80` port, backend internal nginx redirect it to `443` port: `https://a.example.com`, but when i get https port it is not redirect it, opening normally. I have not permissions to change backend nginx configurations.

So, and i have 1 load balancer nginx server, witch route requests to upstreams (backends):

```
upstream backends {
    server 172.20.1.2:443; #a.example.com
    server 172.20.2.2:443; #b.example.com
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name a.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://backends;
        proxy_set_header HOST a.example.com;
    }
}
```

when i get response from second backend (`b.example.com`) my URL in browser is changes to `https://b.example.com`, but i requested `https://a.example.com`

Q: How i can get always `https://a.example.com` url from both backends? For example, when `a.example.com` backend not responding, lb request to second backend (`b.example.com`), but response url must be `a.example.com`
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for routing of https(443) url you need to listen on 443 in nginx also. Eg.

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         a.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     a.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key a.example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
   
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://backends;
        proxy_set_header HOST a.example.com;
    }
}
```

and for dynamic routing to any upstreams try this :

```
upstream backends {
    least_conn;
    server 172.20.1.2:443; #a.example.com
    server 172.20.2.2:443; #b.example.com
}
```

Hope this will works for you.

**Helpful Links :-**
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/